# Problems send Javascript Array to Web API method with List<T> parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS $http to send data to my Web API server.
I don't know why, but my JS Array is not going to the server side, it's going NULL, the id is going OK.

This is what I have:

Client-Side:

```
var dataArray = [
     {
        Prop1: "4674279"
     }
];

var id = 1;

$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost/Services/Controller/Method',
    auth : true,
    data: {
        'id' : id,
        'items' : dataArray 
    },
    headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         if (status === 200) {
              return data;
         }
     })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log('[ERROR] Status Code:' + status);
    });
```

Server-Side:

```
public partial class Item
{
     public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public ReturnType Method(int id, List<Item> items)
{

}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I've tried JSON.stringify and so on, but wont works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do post to two parameter on the controller method. The standard mediatypeformatter would format to a single object

Your options are to

Create a class such as

```
public class ListItems {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public List<Items> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Or make the id as part of url such as

`http://localhost/Services/Controller/Method/:id`

Then the api method would look like

```
public ReturnType Method(int id, [FromBody]List<Item> items)
```

Comment: Yeah right, I solve it diff, changing the controller for a dynamic, such as: 
public dynamic Method(dynamic requestObj)
And then process the JSON data to the Properties.

This solves.

Thanks.